# Need Help Creating Griffin Howling Sound

Tags: sound, sound-effects

I'm currently working on my RPG game, and I'm trying to design a unique sound for the griffin's howl. I have a specific sound in mind, but I'm having trouble finding good references for it. Can anyone share their experiences on how they conceptualize abstract sounds like this?

Also, if any of you have tried recording similar sounds before, I'd love to hear about your success or any tips you might have.

Comment: Hit your small toe on a corner twice in a row when you don't expect it (I agree, that will be a bit hard to catch on record). Keep recording and you will get some goblin sounds as a bonus

Comment: Well, it's an eagle & a lion - that should be good for starters. Combined with stubbed toe if appropriate ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at Buckbeak's sound (the griffin in Harry Potter)

It sounds like a chicken plus a dinosaur.

Chicken samples are easy to find and there are also tutorials on how to make dinosaur sounds